# SELECT AND UPDATE values in MYSQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have below table..

```
CREATE TABLE Coupons (
    cid INT(11) PRIMARY KEY,
    coupon_name  VARCHAR(255),
    partner     VARCHAR(255),
    is_active   INT(1)
);
INSERT INTO `table_name`(cid,coupon_name,partner_name,is_active) VALUES (0,'SWIGGYONE','SWIGGY',1);
INSERT INTO `table_name`(cid,coupon_name,partner_name,is_active) VALUES (1,'ZOMATOONE','ZOMATO',1);
INSERT INTO `table_name`(cid,coupon_name,partner_name,is_active) VALUES (2,'SWIGGYONE','SWIGGY',1);
INSERT INTO `table_name`(cid,coupon_name,partner_name,is_active) VALUES (3,'ZOMATOTWO','ZOMATO',1);
```

I wish to fetch one ACTIVE coupon from each partner and update its is_active col to 0.

Any suggestions?
I am using MYSQL 5.7

EDIT:

I wish to fetch those records too whose `is_active` is set to 0.

I dont have enough knowledge of transactions or @variables used in MYSQL 5.7

Comment: Yep, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Hacker315: The close and down votes are happening because your question is very thin on things like sample data or effort shown.  Please remedy this to avoid being closed.

Comment: 1) Why you do not use partners table and `partner_id` referencing column? 2) From practice - coupons have some validity time so the table must contain coupon date column, and the coupon with the validity end date closest to current date must be deactivated.

Comment: I also wish to retrieve those records.. whose `is_active` is set to 0..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE Coupons AS updated_table_copy
  JOIN ( SELECT partner, ANY_VALUE(cid) cid 
         FROM Coupons
         WHERE is_active
         GROUP BY partner ) AS what_rows_to_update USING (partner, cid)
SET updated_table_copy.is_active = 0;
```

If you want to update some definite coupon then use `MIN()`/`MAX()` instead of `ANY_VALUE()`.

If `is_active` may have NULL value which means "active" state (too) then use `WHERE COALESCE(is_active, 1)`.

---

> I also wish to retrieve those records.. whose is_active is set to 0..
>
> I need to write that stored proc..

It may be something like this (approximate code, idea only):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE update_coupon_table
BEGIN
    SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (cid INT) ENGINE = Memory;
    START TRANSACTION;
        INSERT INTO tmp (cid)
            SELECT MIN(cid)
            FROM Coupons
            GROUP BY partner;
        UPDATE Coupons
            JOIN tmp USING (cid)
            SET Coupons.is_active = 0;
    COMMIT;
    SELECT Coupons.*
        FROM Coupons
        JOIN tmp USING (cid);
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tmp;
END
```

Comment: I also wish to retrieve those records.. whose `is_active` is set to 0..

Comment: @hacker315 You must use another query for this - MySQL have no OUTPUT clause. But the table does not contain updated_at column or any other flag - so if you need only rows updated by the above query then you need at least 3 queries. I'd recommend to compact them into stored procedure.

Comment: yes, I need to write that stored proc.. I need help in that.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you update with exact syntax please? @Akina

Comment: @hacker315 I don't understand your last phrase.

Comment: I mean, the approximate code that you added, could you give proper version of that? It seems to show some error.

Comment: @hacker315 No. Transactional procedures must be tested in special environment - I have no it. And if the errors are syntax ones you may fix them by yourself easily, I hope...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217533/discussion-between-hacker315-and-akina).

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
UPDATE Coupons
SET is_active = 0
WHERE cid IN (SELECT cid FROM (
                 SELECT c1.cid FROM Coupons c1
                 INNER JOIN
                 (
                     SELECT partner, MIN(cid) AS min_cid
                     FROM Coupons
                     WHERE is_active = 1
                     GROUP BY partner
                 ) c2 ON c2.partner = c1.partner AND c2.min_cid = c1.cid
                 WHERE c1.is_active = 1
             ) t );
```

This approach is to deactivate one record for each partner, arbitrarily corresponding to the smallest `cid` value per partner group.

Comment: I also wish to retrieve those records.. whose `is_active` is set to 0..

Comment: Then you need another select query for that.